# How can I GET information from a RESTful interface and use it in my Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, json, rest

I've got a RESTful interface where the contents of a database are displayed. What I need is to connect on that interface by my Javascript code and retrieve  information. 
To be more specific, the only information I have for the RESTful interface is its URL.
I want to connect by my application over the internet to this URL and retrieve the requested information (for example all the information stored in the database for the item with id=1).
I am using JQuery mobile because I am developing a mobile application for iPhone using PhoneGap. I think I might have to use JSON but I don't know where exactly. Can you please provide me with references on how to do this?

Comment: Are you using a JavaScript framework, such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com) or [MooTools](http://mootools.net)?

Comment: It will depend on the RESTful interface you're using. You'll want to use Ajax if it's on the same domain, or JSONP for cross-domain, but your interface needs to support it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simpler than I thought, and the references can be found in here: [JQuery official page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

My problem was solved by the use of the following function:

```
var jqxhr = $.getJSON("example.json", function() {
        //functionality
    })

    // perform other work here ...

    // Set another completion function for the request above
    jqxhr.complete(function(){ alert("complete"); });
```